# Match everyting after second occurence of a word

Tags: r, regex

i have a string in R and i would like to match everything after 2nd occurence of a word using a regex

Ex: return everything after 2nd occurence of `is`

```
"This is a string of example. this is what i should get in return".
```

Expected output

```
what i should get in return
```

I've tried something like `([^is]+)(?:is[^is]+){2}$` but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: You could count the second occurrence from the left `^.*? is .*? is (.+)$` and us a capturing group https://regex101.com/r/Xqsid9/1

Answer (score 2):

Using the `stringr` package you could use `str_locate_all()` with `str_sub()`. This extracts where the second instance (`[2,`) of the s in `"is"` (`[, 2]`). And adds one (`+ 1`) so it starts one character to the right of where `"is"` ends.

```
str_sub(text, str_locate_all(text, "\\bis\\b")[[1]][2, 2] + 1)
[1] " what i should get in return"
```

**Data**:

```
text <- "This is a string of example. this is what i should get in return"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a PCRE pattern like

```
^(?>.*?\sis\s+){2}\K.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tHU1wl/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?>.*?\\sis\\s+){2}` - an atomic group matching two occurrences of:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `is` - a word `is`
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

[R demo](https://rextester.com/OSOMG66385):

```
x <- "This is a string of example. this is what i should get in return"
regmatches(x, regexpr("^(?>.*?\\sis\\s+){2}\\K.*", x, perl=TRUE))
## => [1] "what i should get in return"
```

With `stringr`:

```
stringr::str_match(x, "^(?>.*?\\sis\\s+){2}(.*)")[,2]
```

Comment: @Andrew Ok, I edited it to match the requirements exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *unglue* :

```r
txt <- "This is a string of example. this is what i should get in return"

library(unglue)
unglue_vec(txt, "{=.*?} is {=.*?} is {x}")
#> [1] "what i should get in return"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>